# How to update iOS11 Beta

Tags: software-update, ios, beta

I have already installad iOS11 Beta 1 with [Apple Beta Software Program](https://beta.apple.com).

But there are new beta releases (Beta 2 and Beta 3), when I navigate to settings-general-software update, it says,

> iOS 11.0 Your software is up to date

I have also checked version, it's 11.0 (15A5278f) which is actually Beta 1.

Why don't new updates appear in software update section? How can I install new beta versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.

On your phone log onto beta.apple.com with the AppleID you used to sign up for the public beta.

There should be a link, once you log on, to tap on to download the correct profile that will then kick off the next available IOS Beta release.

Comment: this solved my problem and I installed Beta 2, but I'm not able to install Beta 3, have you installed beta 3?

Comment: The public betas are not released in sync with the developer betas. They are two different animals and not released at the same time. I imagine that the dev betas are tested by developers before the public betas are released. But I am just guessing on that...

Comment: :) that's a little bit interesting, I really don't remember whether I installed the developer or public beta for the first time. Anyway, I can handle it with Beta 2, no problem and thanks for help.

Comment: i've installed Beta 2 but the version number is 15A5318g which is actually Beta 3. https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/ios-11-beta-3-changes-bug-fixes-enhancements-etc.2055891/